# Displaying max price with grouped products

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

Is there a way for me to display the **highest price** rather than the lowest price on a grouped product.

I've had a look in `price.phtml` from `template/catalog/product` but can't quite see how this would be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add this code into catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <?php
        $_associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product); 
        $prices = [];
        $grouped_price = 0;
        $price_difference = 0;

        foreach($_associatedProducts as $_item) {
            $id = $_item->getId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

            $prices[] = $product['price'];

            if ($product['special_price']) {
                $grouped_price += $product['special_price'];
                $price_difference += $product['price']-$product['special_price'];
            } else {
                $grouped_price += $product['price'];
            }
        }

        arsort($prices); // get highest price
        $price_array = array_keys($prices);
        $highest_price = $prices[$price_array[0]];
    ?>
    <div>
        Highest price:
        <?= Mage::helper('core')->currency($highest_price) ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        Total price for all these products:
        <?= Mage::helper('core')->currency($grouped_price) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($price_difference): ?>
        <div>
            Total save with all these products:
            <?= Mage::helper('core')->currency($price_difference) ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also I've displayed grouped items sum and total discount. Hope it helps!

Comment: great helpful answer